# Conversion not valid from char to const char*

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I have made this program to find out keywords and identifier in lex when a program is provided as a file to lex

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

void keyw(char *p);
int i=0,id=0,kw=0,num=0,op=0,n=0;
char s[32];
char keys[32][10]={"auto","break","case","char","const","continue","default",
"do","double","else","enum","extern","float","for","goto",
"if","int","long","register","return","short","signed",
"sizeof","static","struct","switch","typedef","union",
"unsigned","void","volatile","while"};

int main()
{
    char ch,str[25];
    char seps[]=" \t\n,;(){}[]#\"<>";
    char oper[]="!%^&*-+=~|.<>/?";
    int j;
    char fname[50];
    FILE *f1;
    printf("enter file path\n");
    scanf("%s",fname);
    f1 = fopen(fname,"r");
    if(f1==NULL)
    {
        printf("file not found");
        return 0;
    }
    while((ch=fgetc(f1))!=EOF)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=14;j++)
        {
            if(ch==oper[j])
            {
                str[i]='\0';
                keyw(str);
            }
        }   
        for(j=0;j<=14;j++)
        {
            if(i==-1)
                break;
            if(ch==seps[j])
            {
                if(ch=='#')
                {
                    while(ch!='>')
                    {
                        ch=fgetc(f1);
                    }   
                    i=-1;
                    break;
                }
                if(ch=='"')
                {
                    do
                    {
                        ch=fgetc(f1);
                    }   
                    while(ch!='"');
                    i=-1;
                    break;
                }
                str[i]='\0';
                keyw(str);
            }
        }
        if(i!=-1)
        {
            str[i]=ch;
            i++;
        }
        else
            i=0;
    }
    return 0;
}

void keyw(char *p)
{
    int k,flag=0;
    for(k=0;k<=31;k++)
    {
        if(strcmp(keys[k],p)==0)
        {
            for(n=0;n<33;n++)
            {
                if(strcmp(s[n],p)==0)
                    continue;
                else
                {
                    strcpy(s,p);
                    cout<<s[n]<<"is a keyword";
                    flag=1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag==0)
    {
        if(isdigit(p[0]))
            num++;
        else
        {
            if(p[0]!='\0')
                printf("%s is an identifier\n",p);
        }   
    }
    i=-1;
}
```

//  Errors :
    lex.cpp: In function ‘void keyw(char*)’:
    lex.cpp:91:18: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
         if(strcmp(s[n],p)==0)
                      ^
    In file included from lex.cpp:4:0:
    /usr/include/string.h:144:12: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘int strcmp(const char*, const char*)’ [-fpermissive]
     extern int strcmp (const char *__s1, const char *__s2)

Comment: `s` is a `char[]`.  `s[n]` is a `char`.  `p` is a `char *`

Comment: Can you please remove all irrelevant code so your example still reproduces the error. Provide a [MCVE] please.

Comment: actually if i will remove the code then  the lex will not work

Comment: void keyw(char *p)
{
    int k,flag=0;
    for(k=0;k<=31;k++)
    {
        if(strcmp(keys[k],p)==0)
        {
            for(n=0;n<33;n++)
            {
                if(strcmp(s[n],p)==0)
                    continue;
                else
                {
                    strcpy(s,p);
                    cout<<s[n]<<"is a keyword";
                    flag=1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
   
    }
    i=-1;
}

Comment: So what? Right now you have a compiler error so nothing works. Less code means a smaller surface area to search for the error's cause.

Comment: You seem to be flipping back and forth between C and C++ code styles. This tends toward inferior results.

Comment: Write your code with more structure, it's a mess. You can't simply add indentation levels to it, that's one good reason to use function. Code doesn't only have to work, it has to be easily understandable, if it's not you risk having undecipherable bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
keyw(str);
```

Instead of that you need:

```
keyw(&str);
```

The function keyw(char *p) needs a pointer or an address.